# Extending base model classes for specific use cases

Tags: c#, oop

We have an application that on the whole is used as a "generic" product by a number of different customers, with generally the same features available to all of them. There are, however, some individually tailored components, especially pertaining to data imports from the customers' respective internal systems.

So far, that mostly meant transforming different input formats into the same data structures, but it is increasingly becoming important to keep additional customer specific data for some types and use it again in select parts of code that also "know" about this specific customer. That generally won't be a lot of different places throughout the application.

To do it without "polluting" the core model classes, that "extensibility" is currently achieved by having the classes in question derive from `DynamicObject` and then having some code to dynamically tack on properties keyed with magic strings and in other places check for those and retrieve them, which isn't even type safe, as you need to know what to cast a possible value to.

I am rather unhappy about this and would like to propose a solution that feels a bit less like "monkey patching" and is more idiomatic in a statically typed environment. The question is what the best option is to achieve that. (An additional requirement is that the additional data should be easy to serialize/deserialize with the rest of the object.)

- The "obvious" thing in an object-oriented language would of course be subclassing the model types, but that creates a number of new issues around object creation and copying and is generally not something I like all that much (and it simply violates "composition over inheritance").
- A solution that still uses inheritance but limits its impact would be adding a single property `ExtensionData` to the actual class, its type being an empty `*ExtensionData` class that is then subclassed per customer. Using that does involve some type checking and casting for the actual extension data object, but beyond that, it would be completely type safe. I think this is my preferred way right now.
- Something that is very similar to the dynamic approach used so far would be replacing the typed object from the previous variant with a `Dictionary<string, object>`. I think that's still better than what's happening now, but it has the same fundamental problem of being dynamically typed and using magic strings (even though they would be stored as constants, of course).

The extension data is not expected to be actually dynamic; once it is known for which customer data is being imported, we are in a well-defined subdomain with no surprises as to what's in the data that is being imported.

(As is so often the case, this would be easier in F#, where I could either use scoped extension properties or have `ExtensionData` be a DU where each case holds a customer specific record type that would be unambiguously identified via pattern matching.)

What is the most 'idiomatic' and maintainable way to do this in C#? Do any of the mentioned alternatives have huge advantages or flaws I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
public class BaseClass
{
    Dictionary<Type, object> propertys = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void Add<T>(T instance)
    {
        propertys[typeof(T)] = instance;
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return (T)propertys[typeof(T)];
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Add<string>("Hello World");

        string helloWorld = Get<string>();
    }
}
```

Limitation is you can only add one instance/property for a given type.

If performance is not an issue another solution could be the following.
But be aware using Expressions like this is slow(er). You give it a lambda, but the implicit conversion to Expression takes some time

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

// There will never be an implementation of this interface
// Its only there to "define" the property names and types without
// magic strings and in a type safe way
public interface IBaseClassExtension
{
    public string ExtensionProperty { get; set; }
    public int ExtensionProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    Dictionary<string, object> propertys = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Add<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expr, U instance)
    {
        var propExpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
        // The declaring types name could be used in addition to be sure there 
        // is no naming conflict with members of other types that have the same member name
        //string name = propExpr.Member.DeclaringType.FullName + propExpr.Member.Name;
        propertys[propExpr.Member.Name] = instance;
    }

    public U Get<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expr)
    {
        var propExpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
        //string name = propExpr.Member.DeclaringType.FullName + propExpr.Member.Name;
        return (U)propertys[propExpr.Member.Name];
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Add<IBaseClassExtension, string>(bce => bce.ExtensionProperty, "Hello World");
        string helloWorld = Get<IBaseClassExtension, string>(bce => bce.ExtensionProperty);
    }
}
```

Both solutions can be used in a type safe way, even the dictionary is only knowing objects

If you have time to wait for C# 6.0 the new nameof operator should be much faster than using Expressions. But you would loose some type safeness.

```
public interface IBaseClassExtension
{
    public string ExtensionProperty { get; set; }
    public int ExtensionProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    Dictionary<string, object> propertys = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Add(string name, object instance)
    {
        propertys[name] = instance;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string name)
    {
        return (T)propertys[name];
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Add(nameof(IBaseClassExtension.ExtensionProperty), "HelloWorld");
        string helloWorld = Get<string>(nameof(IBaseClassExtension.ExtensionProperty));
    }
}
```

Edit:

If the number of extension propertys/data is not that much another solution could be to make the base model generic

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class BaseClass<T, U, V> : BaseClass
{
    public T Extension1 { get; set; }
    public U Extension2 { get; set; }
    public V Extension3 { get; set; }
}

public class ClassThatIsUsingSpecificBaseClass
{
    public void Test(BaseClass<int, int, string> baseClass)
    {
        //baseClass.Extension1 ...;
        //baseClass.Extension2 ...;
    }
}

public class ClassThatIsUsingBaseClass
{
    public void Test(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
    }
}
```

This would be typesafe, no casts are involved and there would be only one BaseClass derivated and not one for every unique customer requirement/data

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the most idiomatic way would be, but I agree with you that I would prefer a solution that uses aggregation.

If you set this up in a specific way, using a set of marker interfaces and helpers, with preferably only one concrete implementation per (customer per) interface, you can make this relatively type safe and also provide some generic access by having infrastructure that allows mapping this data to e.g. a dictionary.

I created a very rough prototype implementation, just to illustrate some ideas. I will post the highlights here, a "full" example can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bed267ad40135a1ec364) (around 200 lines).

We start off by having two marker interfaces for an extendable class and extension data class respectively, that are easily discoverable using reflection.

```
// Marker interface, allowing reflection & discovery
public interface IExtendable {}

// Marker interface, allowing reflection & discovery
public interface IExtensionData {}
```

And we make this more type save and fix the aggregation relationship:

```
// Making it type safe
public interface IExtendableOf<T> : IExtendable where T : class, IExtendable 
{
    IExtensionDataFor<T> ExtensionData { get; set; }
}

// Making it type safe & discoverable through reflection.
public interface IExtensionDataFor<T> : IExtensionData where T : class
{
}
```

Next, we define an interface that is to be implemented by the provider of specific pieces of extension data for a specific customer.

```
// Factory implemented for each specific customer, discoverable.
public interface IExtensionProvider 
{
    IExtensionDataFor<TExtendable> CreateExtensionData<TExtendable>()
        where TExtendable : class, IExtendableOf<TExtendable>;

    IExtensionDataFor<TExtendable> CreateExtensionDataFor<TExtendable>(TExtendable instance)
        where TExtendable : class, IExtendableOf<TExtendable>;
}
```

To make it concrete (using a silly example), lets suppose in your "generic" product, you have a class `PhoneNumber`, like this:

```
// Example "core" class with extension data
public class PhoneNumber : IExtendableOf<PhoneNumber>
{
    public enum Kind { Internal, External }
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public Kind NumberKind { get; set; }
    public virtual IExtensionDataFor<PhoneNumber> ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

And in your "CustomerOne" data extensions assembly you have the extension defined for this class, as:

```
// Customer specific extension data for a phone number
public class PhoneNumberExtension : IExtensionDataFor<PhoneNumber>
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
}
```

Then, omitting the plumbing that is present in the gist, you could use it e.g. like this:

```
// A quick & dirty example.
public static class TryExtensions
{
    static TryExtensions()
    {
        ExtensionProvider.Use(new TryOuts.ExtensionData.CustomerOne.ExtensionProvider());
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        var phoneNumberOne = new PhoneNumber { NumberKind = PhoneNumber.Kind.Internal, AreaCode = "(231)", Number = "567 891 123" }.Extend();
        var phoneNumberTwo = new PhoneNumber { NumberKind = PhoneNumber.Kind.External, AreaCode = "(567)", Number = "555 666 777" }.Extend();
        Console.WriteLine("Phone Number 1: {0}", phoneNumberOne.ExtensionData.ToDictionary()["Prefix"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Phone Number 2: {0}", phoneNumberTwo.ExtensionData.ToDictionary()["Prefix"]);
        CodeThatKnowsCustomerOne(phoneNumberOne);
    }

    public static void CodeThatKnowsCustomerOne(PhoneNumber number)
    {
        var extensionData = number.ExtensionData as TryOuts.ExtensionData.CustomerOne.PhoneNumberExtension;
        Console.WriteLine("Prefix: {0}", extensionData.Prefix);
    }
}
```